# How do I rebase my branch on top of a squashed merge?

Tags: git

Here's my set up, it's easier to ask with a picture. Appreciate any help :)

[image]

Comment: Hi, for the record, the guidelines insist on posting *text* rather than images

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
git rebase --onto master F featureb # just rebase the revisions _past_ F
```

The conflicts are happening because with a normal rebase, git will try to apply D, E and F on top of the revision that "squahed them" (but git has no idea of that... to git D+E+F is just *another* revision like any other without any relation to the original D, E and F).